# Are the instructions available in source.android.com for building android source outdated?

Tags: android, build

I have been trying to build the android source by following the instructions posted [on the official site](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).

However, it looks to me that the steps are bit outdated with the current repositories of Ubuntu 10.04.4 (example: The default gcc is gcc 4.4 now).

The instructions present in the site recommends 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04. Ironically, in the Ubuntu 10.04 download page, it recommends 32 bit.

Having tough time with multiple incompatibility issues. Most of which were already discussed in stack overflow itself over a period of two years.

Running out of internet bandwidth by repeatedly downloading such huge repo.

Has anybody successfuly built the android source code recently? If so could you please point to me any documentation?

> `prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/msgfmt.o: in function icu_46::MessageFormat::toPattern(icu_46::UnicodeString&) const:external/icu4c/i18n/msgfmt.cpp:827: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for icu_46::PluralFormat'`
>   `prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/msgfmt.o: in function icu_46::MessageFormat::toPattern(icu_46::UnicodeString&) const:external/icu4c/i18n/msgfmt.cpp:827: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for icu_46::SelectFormat'`
>   `prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/numfmt.o: in function icu_46::NumberFormat::makeInstance(icu_46::Locale const&, icu_46::NumberFormat::EStyles, UErrorCode&):external/icu4c/i18n/numfmt.cpp:1206: error: undefined reference to 'icu_46::NumberingSystem::createInstance(icu_46::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)'`
>   `prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/numfmt.o: in function icu_46::NumberFormat::makeInstance(icu_46::Locale const&, icu_46::NumberFormat::EStyles, UErrorCode&):external/icu4c/i18n/numfmt.cpp:1215: error: undefined reference to 'icu_46::NumberingSystem::isAlgorithmic() const'`
>   `prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/numfmt.o: in function icu_46::NumberFormat::makeInstance(icu_46::Locale const&, icu_46::NumberFormat::EStyles, UErrorCode&):external/icu4c/i18n/numfmt.cpp:1200: error: undefined reference to 'icu_46::NumberingSystem::createInstance(icu_46::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)'`
>   `prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/numfmt.o: in function icu_46::NumberFormat::getEffectiveCurrency(unsigned short*, UErrorCode&) const:external/icu4c/i18n/numfmt.cpp:1038: error: undefined reference to 'ucurr_forLocale_46'`
>   `prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/rbt_pars.o: in function icu_46::RuleHalf::parseSection(icu_46::UnicodeString const&, int, int, icu_46::UnicodeString&, icu_46::UnicodeString const&, signed char, UErrorCode&):external/icu4c/i18n/rbt_pars.cpp:548: error: undefined reference to 'icu_46::TransliteratorIDParser::parseFilterID(icu_46::UnicodeString const&, int&)'`
>   `make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libicui18n_intermediates/LINKED/libicui18n.so] Error 1`
>   `make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....`

Comment: *"Ironically, in the Ubuntu 10.04 download page, it recommends 32 bit."* - That's a recommendation for the average user *(because there is still linux software that has issues with 64 bit OSes)*. If the android site says you should rather stick with 64, use that. That beeing said, I'm not sure if it will help you when someone says *"Works for me"*. We can rather help you to tackle any issues, but you have to post specific error messages for that. This will also be more helpful for future users with the same issue(s).

Comment: Thanks alextsc. I have started the build again. I will post the specific error message this time around. I just thought of notifying about the same to the webmaster of source.android.com. Hence wanted to check with wider community whether anybody still find the steps correct.

Comment: I have updated the question with the specific error messages.